# Placing PopUp, which is inside a Itemscontrol

Tags: xaml, mvvm, popup, itemscontrol

I've got an itemscontrol, in which all my elements are PopUps. The problem is I do not know how to place them compared to the grid in which the itemscontrol is placed. I've tried using horizontal- and vertical alignment but this does not help. The xaml code I've got so far is:

```
<Grid>     
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding PopUp}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewModel:PopUpTemplateSelector.EndTurnMenuTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Popup IsOpen="{Binding PU.IsOpen}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Design:InGame_NextTurn_UserControl/>
                                </Popup>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ViewModel:PopUpTemplateSelector.EndTurnMenuTemplate>
                    </ViewModel:PopUpTemplateSelector>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry man, having trouble visualizing what "how to place them compared to the grid in which the itemscontrol is placed" should look like. Want to provide a quick and dirty image of some sort of what you want, vs what you got?

Comment: @JonasN89, did my answer solve your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest maybe using the following overlay method instead.

[From this Nokia page](http://web.archive.org/web/20140309174830/http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Create_simple_overlay_with_UserControl_in_Windows_Phone):

Overlay XMAL:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowsPhoneSample7.OverLay"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Foreground="Orange" Height="50" Width="480" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Wait" Foreground="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Overlay code-behind:

```
public OverLay()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.LayoutRoot.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
     this.LayoutRoot.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;   
     SystemTray.IsVisible = false; //to hide system tray
}
```

MainPage code-behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Popup popup;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.popup = new Popup();
    }

    private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.LayoutRoot.Opacity = 0.2;
        OverLay ovr = new OverLay();
        this.popup.Child = ovr;
        this.popup.IsOpen = true;
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (s, a) =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) =>  
        {
            popup.IsOpen = false;
            this.LayoutRoot.Opacity = 1.0;
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        this.popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically this answer was a "link-only answer"... and the link was broken. Found an archive link for you and pulled in relevant code snippets. Just wanted to make sure you were aware that this is always the risk of link-only answers which is why they are discouraged here.